# User email rules at server level

Tags: email, exchange-2003, outlook

Is it possible to set up an email rule directly from the exchange server without having to log into the users account and setting up a rule from within their outlook rules?

Basically, I would like to setup a rule saying that the user is not in the office at the moment, email so and so instead.

Comment: What ver of Exchange?

Comment: We use Exchange 2003.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, its is not possible. Out of Office can only be configured by that user within Outlook. (Or you, if you have their login credentials, or resetting their password.)

The only way you are going to change client side rules, is through the client, be it Outlook or OWA. There are no settings with in Exchange that will let you manage an Out Of Office reply.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I have the login credentials, but that user has left, so the computer has been reallocated, but that users email account is still active for certain important reasons.  I don't understand why this cannot be done from the server when out of office messages work even when the users computer is totally switched off.

Comment: If you have the login creds, login to OWA, and change the Out Of Office from there.

Comment: You could also just setup Outlook on any old machine and change it from there as well.

Comment: The reason it works when the computer is off, is that it is a client side rule, stored on the server. The rule is created, and the server follows it.

Comment: So it is not possible to edit that client side rule stored on the server, directly from the server?

Answer (score 2):

This can be achived via out of office within outlook, ensure this is turned on within Exchange System Manager. To setup each individuals Out Of Office you would need to go into Tools > Out of Office > complete the screen.
It is worth noting that out of office can be configured via outlook web access https:\serveranme\exchange\USERNAME if you have the correct rights you can logon this way and configure it.

hope this helps.

Comment: So it's not possible to do this directly from the exchange server for a given user?

Comment: you can do this from the exchange server via OWA - unfortunatly your not able to set rules directly the users from the System Manager,